# How to avoid breaking build when committing Visual Studio Unit Tests in CruiseControl.Net

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I'm having a problem when a project is committed to SVN, which in turn is automatically picked up by our newly set-up CruiseControl.NET server, the UnitTests are failing.

The unit tests are written in the default Visual Studio Unit test framework - which is the problem. I spot that [nUnit appears to be recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92869/nunit-vs-visual-studio-2008s-test-projects-for-unit-testing) as a good alternative. However, that doesn't change my current predicament - I would like a working build without having to re-write every single one of my Unit Tests in the nUnit Framework  (Would converting a MS Unit Test project take any considerable amount of time - it looks the same to me?)

What is the best way for me to proceed now? We are unable to install Visual Studio on the box and our IT department won't allow us access to go fiddling in the registry.

Comment: Fix your build to correctly run the unit tests that you wrote even outside the IDE.

Comment: Though I've not tried, the articles I've read imply that you can run these tests successfully outside of the IDE as long as the IDE is installed upon the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to run unit tests without Visual Studio, but I had moved to NUnit from MSTests and its reasonably easy - as long as you don't use the test context from MSTest(can't remember the real name), all you have to do is to rename the tags [TestClass] -> [TestFixture], etc (there is always 1-1 mapping) and change the usings. Running NUnit tests on the build machine is trivial.

Also you can try to convince your company to buy you a copy of Resharper (preferred), or TestDriven.NET - so you can easily run NUnit tests from Visual Studio.

Comment: This actually turned out to be the easiest method for me. I used this guide (http://dnagir.blogspot.com/2009/04/from-mstest-to-nunit.html) to try and convert them. A few road bumps, but for now - this proved a fairly quick conversion.